# how can I setup room database, when an entity class contain another entity class?

Tags: database, android-sqlite, android-room

This is my api response that I want to store in database in android

```
[
    {
        "teacherName": "ABC",
        "subject": "Science",
        "student_enrolled": [
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "bcd"
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "efg "
            }
        ],
        "id": "jsdf",
        "status": "paused"
    },
    {
        "teacherName": "Rdf",
        "subject": "Mathematics",
        "student_enrolled": [
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "cx"
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "gfsd "
            }
        ],
        "id": "fds",
        "status": "paused"
    },
    {
        "teacherName": "",
        "subject": "Science",
        "student_enrolled": [
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "hg "
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "ncbn"
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "menon"
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********2,
                "name": "xcvc"
            },
            {
                "contact": 9********1,
                "name": "xbv"
            }
        ],
        "id": "cbc",
        "status": "running"
    }
]
```

I want to setup room databse in adnroid

Comment: Sure, go for it! Also see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The only useful reason that you use the `@Entity` annotation is to define a Table. Tables cannot themselves contain tables.

However, you could use the class/object that would be the table as either a column, with an appropriate Type Converter or you could use the `@Embedded` annotation in which case the underlying fields each have a column of their own.

However, it would appear, from the response that you could design the database in various ways.

- You could have related tables for the core elements, Teachers, Subjects and Students and perhaps the overarching Course (jsdf and fds) to which all the above are related. Thus you would have an `@Entity` annotated class (and thus a table) for the four elements and perhaps other `@Entity` annotated classes for associative tables if there were many-many relationships e.g. if a Student could enrol in many Courses (so a Student can have many Courses and Courses could have many Students).
- You could just have a single table for the Courses with a Teacher column/field a Subject column/field, an id column/field, a status column/field and a field for the list of Students, the students being a class/object and a Type Converter which would commonly be a JSON representation of the Student.
- You could event simply have a single column that stores each item from the JSON (API).

The first option would be the correct way from a database perspective.

The second approach is the typical approach, as it appears to be less involved.

The third is little different to storing the JSON/API as a file.

The **second option** could have classes like:-

```
data class Student(
    val contact: String,
    val name: String
)
data class Students(
    val students: List<Student>
)
@Entity
data class Course(
    val teacherName: String,
    val subject: String,
    //val student_enrolled: List<Student>,
    val student_enrolled: Students,
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val status: String
)
class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromStudentsToJSON(students: Students): String = Gson().toJson(students)
    @TypeConverter
    fun convertFromJSONToStudents(json: String): Students = Gson().fromJson(json,Students::class.java)
}
```

- i.e. the Single table (`@Entity` annotated class) that includes a single field/column for the list of students.

  - noting that a Type Converter would be required to convert the list of into one of the four columns types that can hold actual data.

    - TEXT  e.g. String
    - INTEGER e.g. Long, Int ....
    - REAL e.g. Double, Float ....
    - BLOB e.g. ByteArray ....
  - Typically a String is used in conjunction with a JSON representation of the converted component.
- An example of TypeConverters included that utilise the library com.gogle.code.gson

The **first option** could be along the lines of:-

```
@Entity(
    /* Foreign keys are optional but enforce referential integrity (no orphans) */
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Teacher::class,
            parentColumns = ["teacherId"],
            childColumns = ["teacher"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = Subject::class,
            parentColumns = ["subjectId"],
            childColumns = ["subject"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class AltCourse(
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val teacher: Long, /* a reference/map/association to the teacher in the teacher table */
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val subject: Long, /* a reference/map/association to the subject in the subject table */
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: String,
    val status: String
)
@Entity
data class Teacher(
    @PrimaryKey
    val teacherId: Long?=null,
    val teacherName: String
    /* etc */
)
@Entity
data class Subject(
    @PrimaryKey
    val subjectId: Long?=null,
    val subjectName: String
)
@Entity
data class AltStudent(
    @PrimaryKey
    val studentId: Long?=null,
    val name: String,
    val contact: String
)
/* The mapping/associative/reference/relationship table for a many-many relationship
    Has 2 columns, one to reference one table of the many-many relationship,
        the other to reference the other table.
    The primary key is a composite of the the 2 columns.
 */
@Entity(
    primaryKeys = ["courseMap","studentMap"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AltCourse::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["courseMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AltStudent::class,
            parentColumns = ["studentId"],
            childColumns = ["studentMap"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
            onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ]
)
data class CourseStudentMap(
    val courseMap: String,
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    val studentMap: Long
)

data class AltCourseWithTeacherAndSubjectAndStudents(
    @Embedded
    val course: AltCourse,
    @Relation(
        entity = Teacher::class,
        parentColumn = "teacher",
        entityColumn = "teacherId"
    )
    val teacher: Teacher,
    @Relation(
        entity = Subject::class,
        parentColumn = "subject",
        entityColumn = "subjectId"
    )
    val subject: Subject,
    @Relation(
        entity = AltStudent::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "studentId",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = CourseStudentMap::class,
            parentColumn = "courseMap",
            entityColumn = "studentMap"
        )
    )
    val enrolled_student: List<AltStudent>
)
```

- Noting that AltCourse and AltStudent were so named to allow both options to co-exist when compiling the code. As such the code above is tested as far as it successfully compiles.
- i.e. There are now, as would be considered proper from a database perspective, multiple tables (Course, Student, Teacher, Subject and for the many-many relationship between Course and Student the CourseStudentMap table).
- To give an example of utilising the relationships  is the POJO **AltCourseWithTeacherAndSubjectAndStudents**. This:-

  - has the Course embedded
  - includes the single Teacher object according to the value that maps/references the row in the Teacher Table.
  - Likewise for the Subject
  - Includes all of the Students that are mapped/referenced/related to the course (which may be 0-millions if need be)

The following could be the query that that extracts ALL courses as a List (as an example of extracting the data):-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM altcourse")
fun getAllAltCoursesWithTeacherSubjectAndStudents(): List<AltCourseWithTeacherAndSubjectAndStudents>
```